# Hibernate Criteria for "case" in sql

Tags: hibernate, case, criteria

I need to implement this query condition

Select  Count(*), sum(Case When Result = 'OK' then 1 Else 0 end ) from List;

and also " sum(Case When Grade Like 'Kri%' and Result Like 'A%'  then 1 Else 0 end)" in the queries

using the Hibernate criteria

Could you please provide me with the example for the above